Why ssh ignores hmac for some cipher?
I'm reading the openssl source code, and found that when cipher has the auth_len, then hmac will be ignore.
Related line: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/kex.c#L1014
I tried to find out the reason on Google but no luck.
Two cases:
with aes128-ctr cipher, hmac will be used.
But with chacha20-poly1305, hmac will be ignored, since there is an auth_len.
//I'm new to cryptography and ssh,
//Could someone give me a hint.
UPDATE(from dave_thompson_085):
in the '00s when the protocol was developed and specified essentially all ciphers required separate authentication (here, MAC) but over the decade the desirability of 'builtin' authentication was increasingly discussed and accepted; AFAICR all ciphers defined and added in the '10s include authentication and today anyone who proposes a new unauthenticated cipher needs to give a darn good reason.

Some ciphers, like AES-GCM and chacha20-poly1305, have the MAC authentication built-in to their operation, so there is no need for an additional MAC like HMAC. Others, like aes128-ctr, do not have this built-in MAC property so they need a separate MAC calculation, hence HMAC is used.

This also corresponds to old vs new in SSH2: in the '00s when the protocol was developed and specified essentially all ciphers required separate authentication (here, MAC) but over the decade the desirability of 'builtin' authentication was increasingly discussed and accepted; AFAICR all ciphers defined and added in the '10s include authentication and today anyone who proposes a new unauthenticated cipher needs to give a darn good reason.
